# get the mesh from a cloth and restore it in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm converting a Unity 4 project to Unity 5.  I understand that InteractiveCloth has been changed to Cloth for rendering performance reasons.

In my old project, I was saving the mesh of the InteractiveCloth, so I can restore it to its default state when my level starts over

```
// save mesh
netMeshSave = net.mesh;

public void ResetNetMesh()
{
    UnityEngine.Object.DestroyObject(net.mesh);
    net.mesh = (Mesh)Mesh.Instantiate(netMeshSave);        
}
```

Is there a preferred way to get the mesh from a cloth and restore it in Unity 5?

I can see that Cloth.mesh no longer exists in the Unity 5 api

Answer (score 0):

This is the best workaround I've found so far.  It restores the cloth's mesh to the default state, not an arbitrary saved state:

```
 public void ResetNetMesh()
 {
    net.GetComponent< SkinnedMeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    net.GetComponent< Cloth>().enabled = false;
    net.GetComponent< Cloth>().enabled = true;
    net.GetComponent< SkinnedMeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
 }
```